# Blog widget: How can I show blog from one language within the other one?

Tags: blogs, multilingual, impresspages

Let us assume a website in two languages, e.g. German (default) and English. 
Now the blog should be German only and these entries shall be shown automatically on the English page. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think just read the source code and add some kind of a hack. Shouldn't be the rocket science.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. 
Is there a general way in IP to show the content of another page?